# Steam says during game update "not enough free disk space" even though there is clearly enough space

Tags: steam, linux

```
$ df -h | grep -Ei '(/|games|on|tmp)$'
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-0               220G  178G   31G  86% /
tmpfs                    16G   25M   16G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/luks-games  229G  205G   12G  95% /mnt/games
```

Update size is 1.4GB (Cyberpunk 2077), so everywhere should be enough space. What is Steam doing and why 1.4GB update can't be downloaded to a device with 12/16/31GB of free space? Why does it need more space than the update itself, at least 9 times more?

I already tried clearing download cache, verify game files and checked permissions are ok (since than update for an other game was successfully done, so there should be no issues with download or library folder). Steam doesn't even report *where* is not enough space.

How to troubleshoot/fix this? (I don't want to redownload any big game, or remove any game already installed.)

Comment: Are you using combinations of different hard drives/storage devices?

Comment: @Penguin Yes, one ssd is root (`/`) and other ssd is for games (`/mnt/games`, that's where steam library folder is).

Answer (score 1):

It turned out Steam shows incorrect info, it was not 1.4GB but 3.5GB and probably very compressed. I moved one game to other drive, updated CP and then moved the game back.

Comment: I've seen similar things happen, with Steam and other launchers, like BattleNet for COD.  COD is a massive size game, and I think originally it required 120Gb or so space, but during installation, it would stop because the disk filled up, despite having more than 120Gb free.  I ended having to install it on a completely different drive, despite the original drive having more than 120Gb free, and the end result was a game installation of over 200Gb.  Don't know what they mean exactly when they say "requires X amount of space" but it ends up taking way more.  Probably compression as you said.